# ActionBarSherlock only showing two menu items

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a mixed bag of menu items - some are defined in Java code and some are defined in XML.

The ones in the XML all have `orderInCategory` set to something high.

Of the items defined in code, some have icons and some don't. Only on the items with icons is `setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)` called.

So, what I am expecting is for a bunch of icons to show up (as many as fit) and everything else in overflow. However, what I'm getting is just two icons in the action bar and everything else in overflow.

Not sure what is missing. This is on an Archos 43 running Froyo.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is just normal behavior...

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/9dfnA2hnNXg